# Отсортировать числа в масиве С++

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

В массиве нужно переместить положительные числа в левую сторону, а отрицательные в правую, не нарушая порядок. Не желательно использовать сложные алгоритмы сортировки, указатели.
Не знаю что нужно написать в теле цикла, как определить нужную позицию в новом масиве.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, n;
    int a[]={-2,1,4,-3,2,-1,5};
    int b[7]; //масив для отсортированых чисел

    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        if (a[i]>0) {
            //положительные числа
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        if (a[i]<0) {
            //отрицательные
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А числа в массиве в каком диапазоне?(-1000 - 1000)...

Comment: В этом примере 7 чисел. Числа уже заданы.

Comment: Зачем вам на даном примере решать,надо решать в общем виде,тестирующая система задала тест и ваша програма должна для N чисел решить данную задачу,а ограничения на a[i] должно быть

Comment: Можно отсортировать так: sort(a,a + N), где N количество елементов масива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ без библиотек и указателей.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    int a[]={-2,1,4,-3,2,-1,5};
    int b[7]; //масив для отсортированых чисел
    int j=0;

    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        if (a[i]>0) {
            b[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        if (a[i]<=0) {
            b[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Лучше воспользоваться стандартным алгоритмом:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {-2, 1, 4, -3, 2, -1, 5};

    std::stable_partition(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [](int x){return x >= 0;});

    // Печатает `1 4 2 5 -2 -3 -1`
    for (int x : a)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```